# I don't want to send form data back with express, but it does, or does it?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, forms, express

I know the title of this question might sound confusing, but my problem is actually simple. I have these two handlers for `/login` get and post requests:

```
loginRender(req, res) {
        let options = { title: 'Login', layout: 'auth.hbs' }
        res.render('login', options)
}
login (req,res){
        let user = Routes.findUser(req.body.username)
        let passwordCorrect = Routes.hashCompare(
            req.body.password,
            user.password
        )
        if (passwordCorrect) {
            let token = Routes.jwtsign(req.body.username)
            let refreshToken = Routes.jwtRefreshToken(req.body.username)
            Routes.authRedirect(res, token, refreshToken)
        } else {
            Routes.badRequestRedirect(res, '/login')
        }
}
authRedirect(res, token, refreshToken )
{
        let options = {
            cssPath: 'styles/querystyle.css',
        }
        res.cookie('access_token', `${token}`, { httpOnly: true })
        res.cookie('refresh_token', `${refreshToken}`, { httpOnly: true })
        res.status(200).render('query', options)
}
// app.use(urlencoded)
// app.use(cookieParser)
// app.post('/login', login)';
// app.get('/login', loginRender)
```

**Please, ignore all unrelated stuff.**

So, everytime I complete login, I get my webpage rendered and I can actually open inspector and see this:

**Page Inspector**

[image]

**Address line**

[image]

How can I fix that? I want my user to be redirected to dashboard-like page and not to receive his sensitive data in insecure form.

**UPD**

there's also auth middleware that only appends req.username in case we did parse jwt successfully, and there's a little bit of interaction with it, but it does not appear on page until I go to this page manually by writing the address in address line.

Comment: this is request data, which is sent to the express server, and is totally okay. almost all sites do it afaik. For redirecting after login, I guess you have to look for `res.redirect`

Comment: I mean, I see this information be remaining here until I go to some other page manually, even when I refresh this page it doesn't go. I  am afraid that it might not be secure.

Comment: it will be there right, until the whole page is refreshed. that's why you should do a redirect to clean the cache. i don't see it as a security risk as other websites can't access this info. if you want, you can try doing the same thing on SO as well. but SO redirects very quickly, so turn on `Preserve log` in network tab and try it

Comment: Thanks for res.redirect tip, it fixed the address line issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't send the data to the Express server, then you can't read it in you `login` function and you can't authenticate the user.

It is not a problem is the user can use the tools in their own browser to inspect the data that they entered.

You need it to be encrypted in transport (i.e. use HTTPS and not plain HTTP, at least in production) but you don't need to worry about the user finding out their own password.

Comment: So you say it's completely normal that even after entering and sending form you can access this information in inspector in other page?

Comment: Thank you, your answer resolves my question that I've been trying to fix myself for the entire day